# Doing a 2sum algorithm and I'm confused on python syntax

Tags: python, algorithm

so I followed a tutorial to learn how to complete `2` sum and I understand what ever line means but I dont understand why `diffs[list[i]]` returns the `0` index.  I went through the the algorithm with the current arguments and `i` comes out to `3` when it returns the indexes

```
    diffs = {}  # Make a hash map to store values

    for i in range(len(list)):  # Iterate through list
        if list[i] in diffs:  # If  the number you are on is in the has map
            return [diffs[list[i]], i]  # return indexes

        else:
            diffs[target - list[i]] = i


print(twosum([2, 11, 15, 7], 9))
```

Comment: It seems like a contradiction that this would return the first index. 'diffs' is empty on the first run.

Comment: You shouldn't name your variable `list`. This makes your code very confusing, and will cause problems when you try to use the built in `list()` function

Comment: `twosum([2,11,15,7], 9)` should return `[0, 3]`, which it apparently does. what is it that you don't understand?

Comment: if you run this it returns [0, 3] Which is 2 and 7 that adds up to the target @cheery

Comment: @shayanvalaie then what is it that confuses you? it works correctly, no?

Comment: I dont understand why the syntax [diffs[list[i]] which is at the end technically [diffs[list[3]] is 0 @user1984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def twosum(nums, target): 
    diffs = {}  # Make a hash map to store values  
 
    for i in range(len(nums)):  # Iterate through list 
        if nums[i] in diffs:  # If  the number you are on is in the has map 
            return [diffs[nums[i]], i]  # return indexes 
        else:   
            diffs[target - nums[i]] = i 
            print(i, diffs)
```

```
In [4]: print(twosum([2, 11, 15, 7], 9))                                                                               
0 {7: 0}
1 {7: 0, -2: 1}
2 {7: 0, -2: 1, -6: 2}
[0, 3]
```

As you can see from the above output, `7` has index `0` in the dictionary. It's the first element that is added to the dictionary. The reason is that you are saving the **differences** in the dictionary. `target - nums[0]` is `7` in this case because `nums[0]` is `2`.

Then, when you reach the last element, namely `7`, you find it in the dictionary with the index `0`. That is `diffs[nums[3]] == diffs[7] == 0`. And you return `[diffs[nums[i]], i] == [diffs[nums[3]], 3] == [diffs[7], 3] == [0, 3]`.

Also, don't use the name `list` to name your variables.

Comment: the indices are values of the dictionary while the differences are the keys. we put those indices as values in the dictionary here: `diffs[target - nums[i]] = i`. I'm not sure what you mean with automatically. If it means that a dictionary automatically returns the value of a key, given that the key is present in the dictionary, then the answer is yes. Unlike some other languages, like Java, python dictionaries automatically return the value. You don't need to employ a special method for that @shayanvalaie

Comment: got it thank you

Answer (score 0):

On the first run of the loop. `diffs[target - list[i]] = i` sets diffs to {7: 0}. That's how diffs[list[3]] evaluates to 0. Eg.

```
diffs[list[3]]
diffs[7]
0
```

Comment: Okay I understand it now thanks for the explanation